# Get the array elements of the last node in Firebase Realtime Database with Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As shown in the image below, I have a database "table" called `fridge` that has a child called `food`. `food` is an array that can contain one or more elements.
I want to access the last node and fetch the food elements and add them in a list, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

[image]

Thank you for your help

Comment: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("fridge").orderByKey().limitToLast(1)`?

Answer (score 1):

You could follow the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data?authuser=0) and use the limitToLast() method. Keys in firebase are ordered alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to get the data:

```
mDatabase.child("fridge").child(fridgeId).child("food").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
    new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                 String foodItem = postSnapshot.getValue();
                 foodList.add(foodItem);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please though explain what `fridgeId` is and where I can find it?

Answer (score 0):

First, create a list to store those values.

```
List<String> food  = new ArrayList<>();
```

Retrieve the last stored food inside each fridge key

```
mDatabase.child("fridge").child(yourPushID).child("food").limitToLast(1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
    String lastFood = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
    //Add your food to the list
      food.add(lastFood);
      Log.e("Foods found:",""+lastFood);

       }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
  }
});
```

Where `yourPushID`  should be how you are generating those random keys to store your food

Where `mDatabase` is

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase;

mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please though explain more what `yourPushID` is and where I can find it?

Comment: How you generate those LMd4Rtgb_7b77QXK-qZY keys in your db ?

Comment: I add the data from a python script, i don't know how Firebase generates the keys

Comment: Thanks, I'm not at home right now, I can edit my question when I get there, but basically they are push keys, so you will need to get each push key in order to access each food data, you can research a little bit about it, it's done with the getKey() method