# Display a Firebase specific child's array items in a ListView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a python script that adds data in realtime on firebase.
The script uses a camera to detect what food is available in the fridge and adds what's found.
I want to build an android app that fetches the most up to date data (i.e the most recent detection the webcam has made)

For example, in the image below, the last food detection was just `yogurt` and the one before was `yogurt` and `egg`

[image]

I am using the following code to display the available food in a `listview`

```
rv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myrv);
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

final ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, foodList);
rv.setAdapter(adpt);

ref.child("fridge").orderByKey().limitToLast(1).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        String message = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        foodList.add(message);
        adpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

I am expecting to have `yogurt` displayed in the `listview`, yet I am having this error

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
```

I am wondering if that's the right code to get what's in `food` for the most recent `key` and how to fix the `hashmap` error

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the array elements of the last node in Firebase Realtime Database with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52375348/get-the-array-elements-of-the-last-node-in-firebase-realtime-database-with-andro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I ended up with, in case somebody needs it

```
food = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.food);
        rv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myrv);
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("fridge2");
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myfoodList);
        rv.setAdapter(adpt);

        ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(1).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
               // ArrayList message = dataSnapshot.getValue(ArrayList.class);

                GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>>() {};
                List<String> message = dataSnapshot.getValue(t);

                myfoodList.clear();
                myfoodList.addAll(message);

                //myfoodList = message;
                adpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

Comment: Btw, this worked after I slightly changed my database structure and made it look like this: https://imgur.com/a/9uhCDI3

Comment: You have changed the database structure, that's why it works. Anyways, `child("fridge").child("food")` could help to get the data as i mentioned in my answer with the first structure.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
String message = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
```

Might cause the issue since it seems like you are getting `String.class` **hashmap** as `String`.

Try something like this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
```

Or getting child then to `String`:

```
for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

   String myString = ds.child("food").getValue(String.class));

   // print myString or add to list..
}
```

**Edit #2:**

It could also be done by adding another child(`food`):

```
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("fridge").child("food")...// listener
```

With your first structure.

<sub>Use `runOnUiThread()` method then notify data change or etc to effect the UI.</sub>

Comment: I tried the second code but i got this: 
`    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:409)`

https://imgur.com/a/Wn19LQb

Comment: It seems like there is something null in `ArrayAdapter.java` which does not related to this question. However, you probably used `toString()` method inside the adapter and it was null so, you may check like this first : `if(myString != null) {then get the string}`

Comment: Thanks, but the weird thing I don't have the `toString` method at all in my code

Comment: actually `if(myString != null)` removes the error but i'm not getting anything in my list view, which means mystring is actually null . I'm confused lol

Comment: Well now i see. Thanks for adding picture, you may try checking `myString` to see if you're getting the data or not. then trying to add to the list or etc. It may be null which you are trying to add to the list. also call `Notifydatachange` after adding to the list.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try that

Comment: Thank you so much for your time but unfortunately i couldn't get it to work https://imgur.com/a/0W8th7q
it says `incompatibe types` and also for the other way; calling `Notifydatachange` after adding to the list doesn't solve the problem that i'm still getting an empty list view

Comment: So, in this case i'm suspecting that the `dataSnapshot` **might be null** (can't download the data, issue with nodes, wrong array getting or etc). Haven't you tried checking if you are getting the data or not? print the `dataSnapshot` to see what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180285/discussion-between-w-and-h-h10a).

Comment: after child("fridge") you need to add one more child that is that push key generated to store food